# How to write summaries for literature survey?

Tags: research-process, literature-review, literature-search

My professor wanted me to write a short summary (one or two paragraphs max) on each paper. Focus on the salient of the method.
could I use the abstract sentences exactly or should I change the words and write with my own words?
I was wondering if you could tell me whether it is necessary to read whole the papers or it is enough to read abstract and conclusion part?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot know what your professor wants. However, I'd guess that if your professor asked you to write a summary, they expect you to write the summary in your own words.

Answer (score 3):

He has asked you to write a summary of the works. I expect he wants to assess how you write, as well as your understanding of the papers themselves.

Copying the abstracts verbatim not only obstructs this goal, but is also plagiarism. The ideas and words are not your own and you should not try to pass them off as such.

Read the papers carefully and summarise them in your own words.

Comment: should I read whole the papers? What will happen if I just summarize the abstract and conclusion?

Comment: @nikki2 If you study with such an attitude, you may be well stop here. Don't you think that by reading those papers you might actually learn something?

Comment: @ Massimo Ortolano. I do think so. but I have just started finding articles related to my master thesis and I am going to read 60 articles. I need to find top 10 articles among those 60 articles.

Comment: I ask my students to do exactly the same thing.  I use the summaries to assess their writing and technical skills.  By 'copying' or 'paraphrasing' sentences from papers will show that you have a shallow understanding of a paper, and that your English level is poor.  I can very easily tell the technical depth of a student by reading their writing or listening to how they explain technical concepts.